# How much different are the live action and manga versions of "Yamada-kun to 7-nin no Majo"?

Tags: yamada-and-the-7-witches

I ususally read *Yamada-kun to 7-nin no Majo* manga from time to time.
Recently, I heard a Live Action version was aired and completed. But its manga is still ongoing.
So how much of the manga is covered by the live action version? And how closely does the live action version follow the manga version?

Comment: As a side note, the Spring-2015 anime follows the first arc more closely than the live-action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Live Series cover the first arc of the manga (the "First Witch War" as it is called by a character in the second arc).

> WARNING: SPOILER HEAVY.

I won't bother into putting spoiler markings into the answer, or it will be just a wall of yellow strips.

Comparing the live action to the manga, we have the following differences, in no particular order:

1. The seventh witch (Rika Sayonji) is downplayed. Since the story will end just after the ritual, she is not developed, and strikes as mostly comic relief for her no-panties gag.
2. Kentaro Tsubaki is missing.
3. The old building is not mentioned. We never know where the sealed room is. Neither is the arson arc ever mentioned.
4. The ritual takes place in the sealed room, instead of the student council chapel.
5. Leona Myamura is Rika's "Friend". This means Haruma Yamazaki is demoted to a plain antagonist, his character development with Leona is ignored. Also, Leona had her memory wiped in the series, while in the manga she is shut-in as to not lose her memory (she eventually returns and is wiped for a short time).
6. Shinichi Tamaki is missing. The witch-stealing power is given to Yamazaki. He is replaced by Isobe in the series.
7. Mikoto Asuka still has her invisibility power, since She is hinted to be Yamazaki's lover to fill the void left by Leona
8. Ushio Igarashi remains Nene Odagiri's follower at the end of the series, instead of teaming with Asuka as he did in the second season.
9. The witches' wish is subverted in the series finale, into a gag. Rika wishes for panties, and then Yamada is forced to use the cancelling power to wipe the witches' powers. In the Manga, Yamada wishes to remove the power directly.